# Pass javascript array to C# via json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jquery, json.net

I´m using this javascript array:

```
 var exportOptions = [{
            jobName: ""},
            {exportType: ""},
            {attachToEmail: ""},
            {distributorName: ""},
            {vistaNumber: ""},
            {customerName: ""},
            {competitors: ""},
            {agreementType: ""},
            { annualPotential: "" },
            {businessCase: ""
        }];
```

And I passing to ASP.NET codebehind(C#) with this code:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'Epad.aspx/generateReport',
                        data: "{'columnList': '" + columnList + "', 'exportOptions':" + JSON.stringify( exportOptions ) + "}",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        });
```

And reading in C# with this method:

```
public static void generateReport(string columnList, Object exportOptions) {}
```

columnList is a string variable this values I can retrieved from C# but the exportOptions's values I cannot see in the debugger... I can see the names of the exportOptions array key in Object exportOptions(C# Object) but never pass the values...

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved similar issue by this way:

JS code (part of processing function):

```
    var ords = [];
    $(".order-count-input").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() > 0;
    }).each(function() {
        ords.push({                
            GoodsId: $(this).attr("goodsId"),
            Amount: $(this).val()
        });
    });

    var data = {
        orders: ords,
        orderId: id
    };

    var params = {            
        url: actionUrl,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.replace(data.redirect);
        }
    };

    $.ajax(params);
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostOrder(long orderId, PostOrderViewModel[] orders)
```

Model:

```
[Serializable]
public class PostOrderViewModel
{
    public long GoodsId { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! With this very good example I can pass and read the array values to code behind... But now I can't access to array values in Javascript either by index or by key.... Any other help will be appreciated....

Comment: Opsss! Sorry for not update... I found that I can iterate array of object with two for in... like this.... for (var index in exportOptionsList) 
{
   var obj = exportOptionsList[index];
   for (var key in obj) 
   {
       alert("key: " + key + " value: " + obj[key]);
   }                       
}

Answer (score 0):

I would first check that the values are sent from the client side. I would use the browser debugger. There you can set breakpoints and see if the variable you send (`JSON.stringify(exportOptions)`) has values.

You could use the F12 button (either from the Chrome, or Firefox) and use the javascript debugger. In chrome you can do it in "Script" tab. In Firefox you can do it in "Sources" tab.

Hope I helped!