# How do i pass objects to handlers in ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to create an object in the javascript and pass it to handler

```
var EducationalInstitute = new Object();
EducationalInstitute.InstituteId = iInstituteId;
EducationalInstitute=Name;
```

Now i need to pass this in ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "../Handlers/DeleteEducationalInstitutes.ashx",
        dataType: "json",
        responseType: "json",
        cache: "false",
        data: { EducationalInstitute: JSON.stringify(EducationalInstitute) },
        success: DeleteEISuccess
    });
```

The problem is I am not aware of how to get this in the handler as object!

```
var Institute = context.Request.QueryString["EducationalInstitute"];
EducationalInstitute educationalInstitute = (EducationalInstitute)new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(Institute);
```

The value i am getting for Institute is `{"InstituteId":"1"}`

The class definition is

```
 public class EducationalInstitute
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int InstituteID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string InstituteName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Zone { get; set; }
    }
```

I am getting the error

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'namespace.BusinessEntities.EducationalInstitute'."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the way you're creating the model in the javascript:

```
var model= {InstituteId: iInstituteId, InstituteName: iName};
```

where `iInstituteId` & `iName` are vars you've created in the client side code

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "../Handlers/EducationalInstitutes.ashx",
            dataType: "json",
            responseType: "json",
            cache: "false",
            data: {EducationalInstitute:JSON.stringify(model)},
```

Here's an example: http://geekswithblogs.net/pabothu/archive/2011/05/21/passing-a-complex-json-object-to-ashx-and-reading-it.aspx

Comment: I am getting an error 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type projecname.class !!

Comment: still i am not able to convert the json string to class!!
i am getting the same error :(

Comment: From the error, the parameter obviously contains an object type which can't be deserialised into any of your model types.  Can you debug the code and inspect the ["EducationalInstitute"] parameter when it hits your c# method?

Comment: The value i get is {"InstituteId":"1"}

Comment: Have you changed the way you're creating the object in the javascript to use the example I gave?  or are you still using your original method?

Comment: I am wondering how it can be assigned like this if i want to pass objects in the array!?
Like JSON.Stringify(institutes[2])

Comment: Here's an example of that: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778628/pass-javascript-array-to-c-sharp-via-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778628/pass-javascript-array-to-c-sharp-via-json)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it

```
var Team = { EducationalInstitute: EducationalInstitute, Location: "Chennai", Mentor: Mentor, TeamDescription: TeamDescription, TeamId: 1, TeamLeader:"",TeamLogo: TeamLogo, TeamName: TeamName };
```

**Ajax call**

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "../Handlers/CreateTeam.ashx",
            dataType: "json",
            responseType: "json",
            data: {Team:JSON.stringify(Team)},
            success: createTeamSuccess,
            error:createTeamError
            });
```

**C# Code**

```
Team team=new Team();
var teamObject = context.Request.QueryString["Team"];
team = (Team)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(teamObject,typeof(Team));
```